# How can i run a linux executable from any directory in terminal?

Tags: linux

I know that the linux commands like ls, cd and others are executables and can be accessed from any directory. My question is how can i run an executable created by me from any directory in terminal ?

Comment: You can still run it from any directory if you use the right path.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the [`PATH`  variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). It could be set by your shell. Check with `echo $PATH` its current value. It is also used by several [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions. BTW, having a long `$PATH` is bad taste and messy (and could be inefficient).

If your login shell is `/bin/bash` you could edit your `~/.bashrc` (used for [*interactive* shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html)s) to add something like

```
 PATH="$PATH:/something/more"
```

but on several recent Linux distributions, the `$HOME/bin/` directory is already part of your `PATH`, and you might add scripts, executables, or symlinks to them in it.

So (when `$HOME/bin` is mentioned in `$PATH`) I don't recommend extending your `PATH`, but rather adding appropriate executables, executable scripts or symlinks into that `$HOME/bin/` directory.

Of course, if you have some executable in `$HOME/someproject/someprog` you can still explicitly run it with a shell command starting with `$HOME/someproject/someprog`.

Your [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) procedure might also have some installation step. For example, if you use [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) as your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation), you might have an `install` phony target in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) which copies the executable after its compilation into some appropriate place. See also [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) & [install(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html), and [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf).

Look for inspiration into the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), e.g. on [github](http://github.com/).

Notice that many utilities (e.g. `cron` and your [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)) don't use your interactive `PATH` (but some reduced default one). So you might want to give an absolute path of some script when using [crontab(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

The directory that the executable is located in must be available in your `$PATH`.  You change the path by modifying your shell's startup files (typically `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`), adding

```
PATH="$PATH:/some/directory"
```

... where `/some/directory` is the path to the directory where your executables are located.

The change will take effect when you open a new (login) shell.

Answer (score 0):

ls runs from any directory because whenever you execute any program file it first looks in your present directory. If it finds it there it will execute it else it will look at you PATH variable and then try to find it in those directories and then execute it.
e.g 
 ls is not present in you current dir but it is present in one of directory mentioned in path variable. do,
    echo $PATH
    /usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
The output above shows it will check for "ls" in /usr/sbin,/usr/bin,/sbin,/bin 
and so on....

Now you can do something interesting,do
    export PATH=
and now execute 
    ls
    o/p: bash: ls: No such file or directory
because ls is not in your present directory and PATH variable is empty.
Caution: Save your PATH variable value before you run above command.

Answer (score 0):

Or You could use the "alias" command, pointing to Your "executable".
If You put the "alias" in  Your ".bashrc" file, then Your chosen "alias" will "call Your executable" in all shells.
[.bashrc is the "config file" for bash-shell, it's normally saved in Your home directory]
Making it work as any other "shell command", whithout having to change Your "path" variable.
This is also a simple way to "bind" scripts that You use often, to short simple "shell commands of Your choosing". So that they are "ever present" in Your shell, which I think is very useful.