# Can't run executables from nautilus

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, nautilus

[(the warning that shows up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0gcD.png) On Ubuntu 18.04, I compiled a c++ sample which only included stdio.h and an empty main function using `g++ test.cpp -o test`
.

No errors popped up and I had no issues running it from the terminal.

However, once I go on nautilus and try to run it by clicking on `test`, a warning pops up, asking me to pick a program to open the shared library.

How do I make sure the program is compiled as an executable/ is seen as an executable by the file manager?

Edit: stat output on the executable (recompiled and changed the name to asdff):

```
File: asdff
  Size: 10600       Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 808h/2056d  Inode: 4200517     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  miguel)   Gid: ( 1000/  miguel)
Access: 2018-05-18 15:22:58.009993285 +0100
Modify: 2018-05-18 15:22:58.009993285 +0100
Change: 2018-05-18 15:22:58.009993285 +0100
Birth: -

df output on the same executable:


Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8      128206036 102694048  18956444  85% /

desktop entry:

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=asdff
Exec=./home/miguel/Desktop/asdff
Icon=/home/miguel/Desktop/index.png
```

Comment: Check that you can run executables from the partition where the executable is. This is done with `mount`.

Comment: Also, just to be sure, give your executable another name, `test` may infer with the systems shell.

Comment: Finally, run `stat` on your executable and add the result to your question (--> [edit] <<-- click).

Comment: Provide some [MCVE] and give the exact error message given by running your program in the terminal. Show also the output of `df` and of `stat` on your executable

Comment: Rename your program as `mytest`, and show your `mytest.desktop` file in your question

Comment: Show also the *exact* warning given by Nautilus

Comment: I'm sorry for this question but where do I find the .desktop file?

Comment: **You have to write that  `asdff.desktop` file** yourself, with an editor. My answer gave a link. I guess it could go to `$HOME/Desktop/` but you need to try

Comment: `[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=asdff
Exec=./asdff
Icon=index.png` trying to run this returns that the launcher is not marked as trusted

Comment: Prefer absolute paths in your `asdff.desktop` file, but **edit your question** to show it (inside your question) but don't comment it

Answer (score 3):

I notice that you were trying to use a desktop file. That is good.

[Because Nautilus is patched to remove the ability to execute programs. It's a security problem.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/commit/3a22ed5b8e3bbc1c59ff3069ee79755168754916)

Put your desktop file in the right location for the application launcher and open it that way instead of by using Nautilus. This location is `$HOME/.local/share/applications`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes your `test` program lies on your home folder and that `/home` has its own partition, with the `noexec` option (this is the default on Ubuntu).

[`man mount`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) says:

> **noexec** Do not permit direct execution of any binaries on the  mounted
>                 filesystem.

This means your system prevents you from running your test program on your home folder.

If this is true, you can either move your program outside of `/home` or change the way your home partition is mounted by editing your `/etc/fstab` file. See `man fstab`, but basically you want to add the `exec` option.

---

Other hypothesis:

1. For whatever reason, your `test` program does not have an execute premission. Check that with `$stat test`.
2. For whatever reason, the name you gave to your test program infer with the system's shell builtin command `test`. Rename your program.

Comment: I moved the code to Documents, compiled it there twice, returning an executable called asdf and another called bop. I used chmod +r for both but the shared library warning still pops up

Comment: oh yeah, it is, dumb me. I mentioned a warning popped up telling me to pick a program to open "shared library"

Comment: Ho ok, I though you meant a warning at compilation time ^^

Comment: Leaving the executable outside of home just so I can run it by clicking on it is more work than just running it from the console. Do you have any idea how I could get it to work on home?

Answer (score 0):

**Run your program in a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) on the [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), using your interactive [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell).** Be aware of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (you might change it by configuring your interactive shell, e.g. in `~/.bashrc`). Your shell will use [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (after [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))) to run your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) binary (so it should stay on some executable partition, as [answered by YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50412926/841108) and be executable - see [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)). You want to see the *stdout* and *stderr* outputs of your program. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50328574/841108) answer.

Use `g++` with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Avoid naming `test` your program (that name conflicts with [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)). If your executable uses other libraries, you might need to explicit some [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) at link time.

Only when your program is a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) program (e.g. coded for a [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like [Qt](http://qt.io/)) should you care to (eventually) be able to run it in your desktop with a click (details could be specific to your [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)). You'll bother about that much later (and you probably even should not, and leave that burden to your user, or to the [packager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) of your program).

> I make sure the program [....] is seen as an executable by the file manager?

That is a sysadmin question and could depend upon your [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) or [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager). I won't bother at first, but later you might have some [desktop entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) (some file ending with `.desktop`) describing your program. So use an editor to **create that `asdff.desktop`** textual **file** (it probably should go into your `$HOME/Desktop/`  directory and should mention absolute file paths).

> ```
> Exec=./home/miguel/Desktop/asdff
> ```

The `.` is a typo, should be `Exec=/home/miguel/Desktop/asdff` without any dot.

Every program on Linux is started by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (done by a shell, your desktop environment, or some other program). You should **use a shell in a terminal emulator to start** most of **your programs**, especially when developing them. And you certainly should expect your users to run your program with their shell (I hate starting programs with my mouse), perhaps in some [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) combining your program with other ones. Read also about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

Comment: I compiled it with the command `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g test.cpp -o asdff`. No warnings popped up during compilation but the issue remains on the asdff executable. I can run it from the command line
but it still mentions the shared library if I double click it

Comment: **Don't use double clicks to start your program**, at least not till they are completely debugged, with a GUI interface, and stable enough. ***Take the habit of using the terminal***

Comment: I do have the habit of using the terminal, it's just that I actually got this issue from trying to run a program with a gtk3 gui. I wouldn't say I debugged it as far as I could but I intended to actually put the program to use  for myself, so, if it has any bugs, I'll be the only person getting hurt by them. I just made this sample for it to be easier to explain, since the issue didn't appear to be related to gtk3

Comment: That should go into your question; such a context is very important, and your question did not mention it, and it is unclear. Please **edit your question** to improve it and give all error messages there.

Comment: I just chose to leave it out because it acted as weird if I used a simpler program and it'd make explaining easier. Plus, if it gets solved for the sample, there are good odds it also gets solved for the original program

Comment: You could code some [MCVE] using GTK and show it in your question, and its output in a terminal. You also should give the `.desktop` file for it; and of course you need to `chmod u+rx` your executable (but a successful `gcc` does that)